# DEIS no public IP's

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, deis

Following the instructions here :

https://github.com/deis/deis/tree/master/contrib/ec2

to deploy Deis to EC2 into a VPC, Cloudformation stack start up and creates the instances, however the instances does not have public IP's, the subnet the instances are launched into does have auto assign public IP's enabled.

So, without the public IP's I am not sure how to connect to the instances with fleet.

Anyone have any idea's on what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the provision scripts don't assign public IP addresses because the assumption is that the VPC you're provisioning into is internal to your network and that you have other means of access (like VPN).

However, you can easily provision your instances with public IPs by changing [this line](https://github.com/deis/deis/blob/master/contrib/ec2/gen-json.py#L29) to `True` and redeploying.

We know this is confusing, and we're working to rewrite our EC2 provisioning scripts. Thanks for sticking with us!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your computer connected into the VPC somehow, [try this](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AwsVpc) and see if you can VPN into your VPC using it.